# What is the HeavyUsage charge on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a new charge on my AWS account yesterday (~$40). When I dug in a bit it comes from a category called `USW2-HeavyUsage:r4.large($)`. I know what the `USW2` is for and what the `r4.large` is for. What is the `HeavyUsage` referring to?

the r4.large is an AWS' reserved instance where I have reserved r4.large for 3 years. Does this reservation come with a limit on usage?

Comment: Have you paid all upfront, partial upfront, or no upfront? If you haven't paid all upfront it's probably your discounted hourly fee.

Comment: @Tim I've paid none upfront. Does AWS charge this monthly in advance?

Comment: If you've reserved the instance and paid nothing then this is most likely the hourly fee associated with that instance.

Comment: @Tim I calculated the hourly usage for the upcoming month and that is indeed the amount I was charged. Do you know why AWS charges you before the instance's usage instead of at the end of the month (after usage)?

Comment: At the end of the month @JoeB

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have committed to pay for this type of server for three years with a no upfront payment. This line item is the monthly fee for the server you have reserved.

AWS payment is typically in arrears as it's usage base. Given this is taken in advance I guess it's because they know in advance what the fee will be.

Comment: How strange, why dont they just say "Reserving Cost" or something.

Comment: AWS naming can be a bit random / misleading at times. See also the new ["savings plan"](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-savings-plans-for-aws-compute-services/), which is somewhat similar to reserved instances.

Comment: Slight correction needed: "with a no upfront reservation" -> "with no upfront payment"

Answer (score 13):

I was under the impression that AWS discontinued the **Light / Medium / Heavy Utilization** Reserved instances. For their description look here: **[EC2 Reserved Instance Options](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2011/12/01/New-Amazon-EC2-Reserved-Instances-Options-Now-Available/)**, however note that the Light and Medium options are no longer available.

Essentially the **heavy utilization** means that your instance is running 24/7. It doesn't matter how *busy* the instance was, only that it was on.

These options were quite confusing and I believe they're no longer offered.

Hope that helps :)